# Clear input if it's not an email address using Javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My client uses wordpress, the template he's using generates a dynamic form, so I don't know where the html is stored. Therefore I can't use `email` attribute in html, nor I can validate emails using php since I don't have a clue how his theme validates the form.

The form builder generates a `text` input called `cp_email_address` I want to check if the user entered a valid email, otherwise I want to clear the field, I don't have any other option, since I can't wait for the user to submit and then validate, I don't know where the submit code is. All I know is the name, class and id of the email field.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#cp_email_address').blur(function() {
    var testEmail = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
    if (testEmail.test(this.value)) {}; // if true pass 
    else {
        this.value="";
    };
});
</script>
```

- I also tried `target.value= "";`
- And tried `$('#cp_email_address').value = "";`
- And I tried `document.getElementById('cp_email_address').value = "";`

Nothing is clearing the the input field.

Comment: Did you try putting it inside `$(function () {})`? Any errors?

Comment: @PraveenKumar no i didn't try that, will do now, if it makes any difference. no errors

Comment: If you have no idea how Wordpress works, maybe you should hire someone that can edit the plugin to make it actually work the way it should, with serverside validation ?

Comment: @adeneo it's not a plugin, and it generates forms automatically, drag and drop, so it's definitely  coming from mysql (see i have an idea) but you tell me, would you rather dig in mysql database or use jquery and call it a day?

Comment: It's worth noting that that regex will block many valid email addresses.

Comment: @DanielBeck +1. Been there done, done that. Best to leave email address validation to tried and test public framework like JQuery Validation. Nothing worse than getting harassed in the middle of the night because AStes_111.1.8832@tn.ci.gi.nnew.io can't submit with their email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the jQuery Validation plugin because trying to write your own regular expressions for emails is like trying to reinvent the wheel. You'll constantly find emails that are valid that don't validate. You fix your regex and then some other email doesn't validate.

jQuery Validation has validators for a wide range of inputs with email being just one of them. The framework is also friendly to customization allowing you to add your own validation methods dynamically as needed.

Also, instead of clearing the input, just show a message and require them to fix it before allowing them to submit. Clearing a field without telling the user why is going to driver users insane.

Additionally, using change events like `keyup` or `mouseout` on the field and then trying to clear the field can lead to problems.

If you try to validate an email on `keyup` a user will never be able to enter an email address because after typing their first key the validator would fire and the email wouldn't validate cause the field to be cleared. No one would every be able to fill out the form.

`Mouseout` is also not a good solution. Many people, especially those with disabilities, never use the mouse to complete a form. Instead they use the keyboard only using the `TAB` key to go from field to field. For these users `mouseout` will never fire and your field will never be validated. In my experience the `blur` event isn't reliable either. While it is nice to have dynamic validation you always need to make sure all of your fields are valid upon form submission regardless any events being fired or not fired on individual fields.

jQuery Validation takes care of all of these issues for us.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Makes "cp_email_address" required and an email address.</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/site-demos.css">
 
</head>
<body>
<form id="myform">
<label for="field">Required, email: </label>
<input class="left" id="cp_email_address" name="cp_email_address">
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Validate!">
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script>
// just for the demos, avoids form submit
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
jQuery( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    cp_email_address: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    }
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I feel guilty, I should have accepted other answers man, I should have accepted alive to die because his answer worked perfectly, but just because you pointed out that my regular expression is wrong and that there's a framework for that, i had no choice but to accept your answer, man damn it i feel so bad. Thank you so much, and thank I them too

Comment: Its okay. Alive or Die stole Praveen Kumar answer anyway (look at his edits). Also, besides the regex I have updated my answer pointing out more reasons why their suggested answers are not the right way to go. In my professional experience, using Dynamic Forms myself similar to what you describe for thousands of forms this is the best solution for you.

Comment: yes yes yours is clearly by far the best and most elegant answer, thank you so so much

Comment: I have been using this method, but **1@1** is considered a valid email. Is it possible to override that within the construct of `.validate`? (I would have asked this question as a new question, but I have been banned of asking new questions.) So your feedback is very much appreciated.

Comment: MeSo2 - jQuery has addressed [this issue](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/issues/2346#issuecomment-697579666) pointing out they are following the HTML5 spec under which the domain does not need a ".". For example, someone@localhost is a valid email. Also an IP is valid, someone @192.156.1.123. Moreover integers specified for a domain are expanded to an IP, here 1 is expanded 0.0.0.1 resulting in a technically valid address of 1@0.0.0.1. If you want look at the comment in their spec and instructions on how to modify if needed.

Answer (score 2):

As a seasoned WordPress expert, I could say the following:

- WordPress generally doesn't allow you to use `$` for jQuery. Try using `jQuery` instead.
- Secondly, you haven't put inside the `document`'s `ready` event, which is more important.

Ultimately, what I suggest you to do is, combine the both and try:

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $('#cp_email_address').blur(function() {
      var testEmail = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
      if (testEmail.test(this.value)) {}; // if true pass 
      else {
        this.value = "";
      };
    });
  });
})(jQuery)
```

What I had done above is, I created an IIFE, which takes in its first parameter as `jQuery` so, this gets associated with `$` inside the function. So this should 90% work, if you don't get any errors.

Try to add this function in the `footer.php` or somewhere, which definitely gets called.

**Update:** Well, I know this already, but just wanted to be sure. Anyway, as [adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo) pointed out, it is fine to use this variant as well:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#cp_email_address').blur(function() {
    var testEmail = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
    if (testEmail.test(this.value)) {}; // if true pass 
    else {
      this.value = "";
    };
  });
});
```

Again, quoting from his comment:

> If you have no idea how Wordpress works, maybe you should hire someone that can edit the plugin to make it actually work the way it should, with server side validation!

Comment: @adeneo I really didn't know that this was a better way. `:)` Cheers...

Comment: not clearing the email field when i click outside, maybe i should use keyup, and i have an idea how it works, read my comment above.

Comment: No, on keyup would clear the email failed every time you tried to type a character because the email field would not be valie.